# Why am I getting Undefned Jquery-ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have the following code. I have tried to get the values to populate into a `<select>` box, but keep getting `undefined`.

I have toggled `Object.keys` with `Object.values`, but keep getting the same result. Please can someone point me in the right direction.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ddlcomp").change(function() {
    var cid = $("#ddlcomp").val();

    $.ajax({
      url: 'doload.php',
      method: 'post',
      data: 'catid=' + cid
    }).done(function(rows) {
      //console.log(rows);
      rows = JSON.parse(rows);
      console.log(rows);
      $('#ddlsubcat').empty();
      Object.keys(rows).forEach(function(rowss) {
        console.log(rowss);
        $('#ddlsubcat').append('<option>' + rowss.subcat + '</option>');
        //$('#ddlsubcat').innerHTML = $('#ddlsubcat').innerHTML +
        //    '<option>' + rowss.subcat + '</option>';
      })

      //for (var i = 0, len = rows.length;  i < len; i++){
      //  $('#ddlsubcat').append('<option>' + rows[i].subcat + '</option>');
      //}
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: What is the response of your AJAX request?

Comment: '{subcatid: "1", subcat: "Who is you", catid: "1"}`

Comment: You only return a single object, so the loop is redundant. Just use `rows = JSON.parse(rows); $('#ddlsubcat').html('<option>' + rows.subcat + '</option>');`

Comment: This is just test data, in production I will have more, so how do I cater for that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In that case you would need a loop. I'd suggest getting your test data in to the exact format you expect production to use, otherwise you're just asking for things to get broken.

Comment: Thank you @RoryMcCrossan, You pointed me in the right direction. The issue was with the way I fetched the records originally. I was able to resolve that and did a little correction to the code and it is working now. 

Not the  loop is still there and it works with one record.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ddlcomp").change(function(){
      var cid = $("#ddlcomp").val();
      $.ajax({
        url: 'doload.php',
        method: 'post',
        data: 'catid=' + cid
      }).done(function(rows){
        rows =  JSON.parse(rows);
        $('#ddlsubcat').empty();
        $('#ddlsubcat').append('<option> --Select-- </option>');
        Object.values(rows).forEach(function(rowss){
          $('#ddlsubcat').append('<option>' + rowss.subcat + '</option>');
        })
        })
      })
    })`

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it. The problem wasn't with the Jquery Ajax part, but with the PHP code I used to extract the data from database.

```
if(isset($_POST['catid'])){
  $catid = $_POST['catid'];
  $query = mysqli_query($con, "select * from tbsubcat where catid = '$catid' order by subcat ");
  if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
   // while($rows=mysqli_fetch_row($query)){
        $rows=mysqli_fetch_all($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        echo json_encode($rows);
   // }
  }
}
```

The commented out block of code was the original >>> *mysqli_fetch_row*, so I changed it to *mysqli_fetch_all*.

This solved the problem.